# How to get the canvas element by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Currently I'm play with the html5 canvas, the simple code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //THIS WILL NOT WORK!
            //var cv = $("#cv");  

            //THIS WORKS FINE.
            var cv = document.getElementById("cv"); 

            ct = cv.getContext("2d");
            var mText = "hi";
            var x = cv.width / 2;
            var y = cv.height / 2;
            ct.textAligh = "center";
            ct.fillText(mText, x, y);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
    <canvas id="cv" width="200" height="200" style="border:2px solid black">
    Your browser doesn't support html5! Please download a fitable browser.
    </canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The canvas element could only be picked by the method document.getElementById, but the jQuery method is not working. Is there a way to get the original html from the jquery object or am I miss using something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to use the index `[0]` to turn the jQuery object into a DOM element `var cv = $('#cv')[0]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jQuery's `$(<selector>)` returns a collection of nodes (in fact it is "object masquerades as an array" [as the doc says](https://api.jquery.com/get/)) so just use `$('#cv').get(0)` instead of `document.getElementById("cv")`

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) following to get the actual DOM element:

```
var canvas = $("#cv").get(0);
```

Otherwise, you're getting the jQuery object when you only do `$("#cv")`, so methods such as `getContext` will not work.

Answer (score 4):

using get()

http://api.jquery.com/get/

explore the jquery doc, it's very useful

Comment: I have only checked the properties of jquery and forgot the jquery return a set of founded elements.